# What is the linear space of the projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I ran into an exercise saying that

> Any projective variety is isomorphic to the intersection of a Veronese
>   variety with a linear space.

But I don't understand the definition of the term "linear space" in a projective space. In fact, I don't even think $\mathbb{P}^n$ is a vector space.

Can anyone tell me what a linear space is?

Comment: If $\mathbf{P}^n$ is the projective space corresponding to a vector space $V$ of dimension $n+1$, then a _linear space_ in $\mathbf{P}^n$ just means the closed subset corresponding to a (nonzero) vector subspace $W \subseteq V$. You're quite correct that $\mathbf{P^n}$ is not a vector space.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh, I understand now, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh, by the way, if we say a "line" in a projective space, does it mean the subset corresponding to a 2-dim vector subspace of the affine space $V$ (because in projective space, it has dim 1)?

Comment: Dear hxhxhx88: no. Remember that we go from $V$ to $\mathbf{P}^n$ by taking the quotient of $V \setminus \{0\}$ by the action of $k^\times$. So the 1-dimensional subspaces of $V$ correspond exactly to the _points_ of $\mathbf{P}^n$, and a line (meaning a 1-dimensional linear subspace) in $\mathbf{P}^n$ corresponds to a 2-dimensional subspace of $V$.

Comment: Yeah, I realized and have edited by question. But I guess you have been answering already..Anyway, thanks again!